# How to equate a structure array to structure array

Tags: matlab, octave

The following code doesn't work, but I think it's clear what I want to do:

```
my.struct = 1;
foo.bar = my.struct;
```

So that

```
foo.bar.struct = 1
```

Basically I want to fill in the `my` structure array with a bunch of fields and values. Then I want to place that struct as a nested struct within `foo.bar` while retaining the field names.

Comment: you're talking about arrays, but I see none in your example code.. you're sure you're dealing with arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my.struct = 1;
foo.bar = my.struct;
```

this just places the value of `my.struct` (=`1`) in `foo.bar`. Of course then `foo.bar` is just `1`.

I think you're after this:

```
my.struct = 1
foo.bar = my;
```